# How to disable driver signing on 64 bit Vista SP1

Tags: windows

I am testing a driver for which we haven't got WHQL certification yet. So I need to disable driver signing before I install the driver. Does any one know how to disable this on Vista XP1 64-bit version through command line or some other program? I don't want to do an F8 everytime the system boots to disable driver signing.

I tried the following, as mentioned in a few blog posts:

```
bcdedit /set loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit /set nointegritychecks ON
```

They might be working on vanilla vista, but they don't seem to have any effect on vista SP1 for disabling driver signing.

Comment: As far as I know, the driver doesn't need to be WHQL certified. You can create your own certificate and sign it with that as well. WHQL is only required to avoid warnings while installing it, or if it has to go on Windows Update or such.
Google around a bit for confirmation :)

Comment: true, for example, a way to create a driver signing cert: http://www.minasi.com/newsletters/nws0903.htm
Windows DDK tools for generating cat files: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd434863.aspx
But, is there an inbuilt tool for disabling driver-signing requirement?

Answer (score 1):

I believe F8 is the only way to disable driver signing in Vista 64 SP1. Driver signing is meant to enhance system security, thus there isn't a way to skirt around it easily.

Comment: Then how does one test driver installation, before they are signed?